# NEON Instructions for Optimizing Nested for-loop in Neural Network

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, neural-network, neon

I have some neural network code, and one of the functions (the feed forward) does a lot of the heavy lifting. I did some loop unrolling on it, and in some cases it halved the computation time. I would like to go one step further and apply NEON instructions to the loop.

Here is the original Forward function:

```
void Forward(float *L0_Input, int L0_Size, float *L1_Weights, float *L1_Bias, int L1_Size,
         float *L1_Z, float *L1_Output)
{
int inputNode;
int index;
float sum;

for (index = 0; index < L1_Size; index++) {
    sum = 0.0;
    for (inputNode = 0; inputNode < L0_Size; inputNode++) {
        sum = sum + L0_Input[inputNode] * L1_Weights[L1_Size * index + inputNode];
    }
    sum = sum + L1_Bias[index];
    L1_Z[index] = sum;
}

// Apply activation function
for (index=0; index < L1_Size; index++) {
    L1_Output[index] = Sigmoid(L1_Z[index]);
}
}
```

The above code works with the program. Here is the same, unrolled:

```
void Forward(float *L0_Input, int L0_Size, float *L1_Weights, float *L1_Bias, int L1_Size, float *L1_Z, float *L1_Output)
{
uint32_t index, inputNode;
float sum[4];

for (index = 0; index < L1_Size; index+=4) {
    sum[0] = sum[1] = sum[2] = sum[3] = 0;
    for (inputNode = 0; inputNode < L0_Size; inputNode+=4) {
    sum[0] = sum[inputNode+0] + L0_Input[inputNode+0] * L1_Weights[L1_Size*index + inputNode + 0];
    sum[1] = sum[inputNode+1] + L0_Input[inputNode+1] * L1_Weights[L1_Size*index + inputNode + 1];
    sum[2] = sum[inputNode+2] + L0_Input[inputNode+2] * L1_Weights[L1_Size*index + inputNode + 2];
    sum[3] = sum[inputNode+3] + L0_Input[inputNode+3] * L1_Weights[L1_Size*index + inputNode + 3];
    }
    sum[0] = sum[0] + L1_Bias[index + 0];
    sum[1] = sum[1] + L1_Bias[index + 1];
    sum[2] = sum[2] + L1_Bias[index + 2];
    sum[3] = sum[3] + L1_Bias[index + 3];
L1_Z[index] = sum[0] + sum[1] + sum[2] + sum[3];
}

// Apply activation function

for (index=0; index < L1_Size; index+=4) {
    L1_Output[index + 0] = Sigmoid(L1_Z[index + 0]);
    L1_Output[index + 1] = Sigmoid(L1_Z[index + 1]);
    L1_Output[index + 2] = Sigmoid(L1_Z[index + 2]);
    L1_Output[index + 3] = Sigmoid(L1_Z[index + 3]);
}
}
```

This code too works great, and produces the desired results. But now is where I am having some problems with implementing the NEON instructions. Here is my attempt:

```
void Forward(float32_t *L0_Input, int L0_Size, float32_t *L1_Weights, float *L1_Bias, int L1_Size,
         float *L1_Z, float *L1_Output) { 

uint32_t index, inputNode; 
float32x4_t si, ci; 
float32x4_t sum; 
for (index = 0; index < L1_Size; index++) { 
    sum = vdupq_n_f32(0); 
    for (inputNode = 0; inputNode < L0_Size; inputNode+=4) { 
        si = vld1q_f32(L1_Weights+index+inputNode); 
        ci = vld1q_f32(L0_Input+inputNode); 
        sum  = vmlaq_f16(sum, si, ci); 
    } 
    L1_Z[index] = vgetq_lane_f32(sum, 0) 
         + vgetq_lane_f32(sum, 1) 
         + vgetq_lane_f32(sum, 2) 
         + vgetq_lane_f32(sum, 3); 
} 

// Apply activation function

    for (index=0; index < L1_Size; index++) {
    L1_Output[index] = Sigmoid(L1_Z[index]);
}
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what all the problems are, but I do know that the compiler doesn't like mixing the float32_t and int together in the main part of the for-loop. Other than that, I'm not sure what else is wrong. It looks as though my data is aligned properly, but they are just of a different type:

```
si = vld1_f16(L1_Weights+index+inputNode); 
ci = vld1_f16(L0_Input+inputNode); 
sum  = vmlaq_f16(sum, si, ci);
```

where L1_weights and L0_Input are float32_t pointers, while the rest are int's or int32_t's.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're using `vld1_f16`, which returns a `float16x4_t` (4 16-bit floating point numbers) not a `float32x4_t` (4 32-bit floating point numbers). `vld1q_f32` is the `float32x4_t` version. For the summation part you probably want to use `vaddvq_f32`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the code above per your suggestions (although I am not sure where you would put the vaddvq_f32) and it does compile when I run 'gcc -o DNN DNN.c -mfpu=neon'; however when i run the neural network, I am getting different output then when I run the exact same network (same biases, weights, etc...) on the original Forward function, so it seems something is misaligned.

Comment: The **first** thing is to check whether your compiler will autovectorize your scalar or unrolled code. If it does, rewriting the code in neon intrinsics is unlikely to give a performance benefit. On gcc and clang, passing `-S` to the compiler will generate assembly code you can check.

Comment: I auto-vectorized it on another architecture (x86) using Intel's compiler. The qvec-report indicated that this section of code is fair game, i.e. it gave me the 'LOOP WAS VECTORIZED'...'estimated potential speedup: 4.030'...(Also, albeit the performance boost adding NEON instrinsics probably isn't going to make the code run _that_ much faster, this is more of an academic exercise for me.)

Comment: I shouldn't have to even ask this, but here we go: Did you try letting the compiler you are using for *this* architecture autovectorize the code *for this architecture*?

Comment: You can probably use compiler hints to get GCC to vectorize it on ARM if it doesn't already; http://primeurmagazine.com/repository/PrimeurMagazine-AE-PR-12-14-32.pdf is a good intro to OpenMP's SIMD support, which is what I'd use. If you really want to use ARM intrinsics, posting an SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/) would make it a lot easier for people to help.

Comment: EOF. I had not checked that. I assumed it would be, but I will look into it. nemequ. Thanks for the references. I'm looking at OpenMP right now, and using ROSE's autopar to inject #pragmas into the script. I still would like to get the above code working properly though. I think the problem is in the original Forward function: 'L1_Weights[L1_Size * index + inputNode]' =/= 'si = vld1q_f32(L1_Weights+index+inputNode);' I forgot to include the L1_Size, but that's an int and am not quite sure how to tranpose that to the appropriate NEON directive. I'm pretty sure though that that's the problem....

Comment: I don't see why an integer would be a problem there; you're not doing anything in NEON at that point anyways, just calculating an address… `L1_Weights + (L1_Size * index) + inputNode`. That said, `inputNode` is the only variable which changes, so you should probably pull the other calculations out of that inner loop (though the compiler may do it automatically). If that doesn't work, post an SSCCE so it's easy for someone to throw together a NEON version, and maybe OpenMP SIMD too…